# Migrating PrimeFaces to Jakarta EE 9+, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on javax.*

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jakarta-migration

I am adopting Jakarta EE 9 and developing an EE application with EJB and WAR modules. EJB is already done and deployed on GlassFish 6.
Now I want to develop WAR module with PrimeFaces as part of the same EAR and deploy the EAR on GF 6.

I understood the first PrimeFaces version I can use is 10.0.0-RC2 because this is the first release supporting JSF 3.0 (part of Jakarta EE 9). Am I right? But I got below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener
```

Why does PF 10.0.0-RC2 still depend on `javax.*` instead of `jakarta.*`?

The pom dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

PrimeFaces is since 10.0.0-RC2 available in 2 flavors, the default flavor using `javax.*` dependencies and the Jakartified flavor using `jakarta.*` dependencies. To switch between these you need to set the `<classifier>` of the PrimeFaces dependency to `jakarta`.

For example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version><!-- 10.0.0-RC2, 11.0.0, 12.0.0, etc --></version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```